# Get value from ArrayList object in Java?

Tags: java

I know this is a quite basic question, but after reading some SO posts and google I couldn't understand the issue well, so.

I have a map object `data`, a `System.out.println(data)` shows me something like the following on the console:

```
{data=[{engine=engine1, keyword=keyword1, url=url1}, {engine=engine2, keyword=keyword2, url=url2}]}
```

Also, a `data` shows me `LinkedHashMap@11 size=1` on the console.

Now I wanted to have the first "engine" key value of the first array of "data", aka `engine1`.

Before that I tried to obtain the first of the array, so I tried the following, but I get errors.

```
data.get("data")[1]
Cannot evaluate because of compilation error(s): The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object.

data.get("data").get(1)
Cannot evaluate because of compilation error(s): The method get(int) is undefined for the type Object.
```

How can I obtain the "engine1" value from "data"? Thanks for your help.

**edit:**

The code around it is as shown below.
`data` is declared by `Map<String, Object> data`.

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;

~~ 

InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("student.yml"));

Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
Map<String, Object> data = yaml.load(inputStream);
System.out.println(data);
```

(not sure you need this info but just in case, "student.yml" file is as shown below)

```yaml
data: 
  - engine: engine1
    keyword: keyword1
    url: url1
  - engine: engine2
    keyword: keyword2
    url: url2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating answer post question edit;
Please find below, the solution you want;

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class YamlParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("src/main/resources/student.yml"));

        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        Map<String, Object> data = yaml.load(inputStream);
        System.out.println(data); // Prints full map
        List<Map<String,String>> eng = (List<Map<String,String>>) data.get("data"); //Casting object to List
        System.out.println(eng.get(0).get("engine")); // Prints the value : engine1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The map declaration is not by `Map<String, List<Engine>>` but as the added detail above on my question. Sorry for the lack of details since I'm new to Java and didn't think the info was needed.

Comment: So `data.get("data").get(0)` shows me `data.get("data").get(0)
Cannot evaluate because of compilation error(s): The method get(int) is undefined for the type Object.`

Comment: Rewritten answer as per your needs, please find it.

Comment: Thanks for the rewrite. And boom it worked. Thanks

Comment: Nice answer.  I'll just add that the simplest change is to just assign the result of `yaml.load` to a sufficiently defined type to begin with:  `Map<String, ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> data = yaml.load(inputStream);`, which lets you do  `System.out.println(data.get("data").get(0).get("engine"));`.  Same thing really.  Just pointing out that there's no need to break the logic into two phases.  This avoids the need for a cast.

Comment: Thanks @CryptoFool, it helped me to understand the `Map` a little. I wonder Is it something we need to deal with manually? I mean for example what if the data structure was much more of complicated, isn't there any way or library to automatically convert?

Comment: @Lime - My guess is that there are libraries that will help with this, but I don't know of any off hand.  I've written utility functions a number of times that take a structure and a string that represents value you want to extract from the structure.  This case might look something like `get_value(data, "data.0.engine")`.  That function will query the types in the structure and cast things appropriately to get the desired behavior.